# Vue.js getting just some attributes from an array to another array

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core-webapi

Im trying to PUT some of atributes from array Zamestnanci to array archivovany, I tried almost everything and it seems to not work at all. I allways get HTTP error 415 or HTTP 400 because the atributes in archivovany are null.

```
<script>  
import axios from 'axios';
import ZamestnanciService from "../ZamestnanciService";




    export default {  

         name: 'Zamestnanci',  
             data() {  
       return { 

      zamestnanci: [{
        id:"",
        meno:"",
        priezvisko:"",
        pozicia:"",
      }],

      archivovany: [{
        id: "",
        meno: "",
        priezvisko: "",
        datumPrepustenia: new Date(),
        poslednaPozicia: "",
       }]
      ,
      
     

    };  
  },  
          created(){  
             this.getZamestnanci();
             
             
          
                  },
methods: {
      
      getZamestnanci(){  
      axios.get('https://localhost:49153/api/zamestnanci').then(response => {  
      this.zamestnanci = response.data;  
          console.log(response.data);})
          }, //get
      
      archivovat(id){
 
      axios.post('https://localhost:49153/api/archivovany/',this.archivovany).then(res=>{
       console.log(res);})
       },

      deleteZamestnanci(id){
        axios.delete('https://localhost:49153/api/zamestnanci/'+id).then(response => {this.getZamestnanci();})
        if(confirm("chcete archivovať zamestnanca ?")){
      this.archivovat();
      
      }
      },//delete
   
 }

      
      

    

     

    }

    
         
    

 
 
</script>
```

I need to pass id, meno, priezvisko, pozicia to array archivovany and then PUT the data to another table, but nothing seems to work can anyone please help me ?

The data is from asp.net core API

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I solved it my way, I don't know if its the best way but here is my solution.

i created one more object zamestnanec.

```
 export default {  

         name: 'Zamestnanci',  
             data() {  
       return { 

      zamestnanci:"",
      zamestnanec:"",
      archivovany: {
        
        meno: "",
        priezvisko: "",
        adresa:"",
        datumNarodenia:"",
        datumPrepustenia: new Date(),
        pozicia: "",
        plat: ""
       }
```

I created one more axios.get function to load data to the object inside the function Archivovat(id) and there i saved the data from get function to zamestnanec and after that I have put the data to object where i needed.

```
archivovat(id){
        
        axios.get('https://localhost:49153/api/zamestnanci/'+id).then(response => {  
      this.zamestnanec = response.data;
        
        this.archivovany.meno=this.zamestnanec.meno;
        this.archivovany.priezvisko=this.zamestnanec.priezvisko;
        this.archivovany.adresa=this.zamestnanec.adresa;
        this.archivovany.datumNarodenia=this.zamestnanec.datumNarodenia;
        this.archivovany.pozicia=this.zamestnanec.pozicia;
        this.archivovany.plat=this.zamestnanec.plat;
          console.log(response.data);
      
        
        
       axios.post('https://localhost:49153/api/archivovany/',this.archivovany).then(res=>{
       console.log(res);})})
       },
```

I'ts really messy code but it solved my problem.